# Noughts and Crosses checking if someone has won

Tags: java, operators

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class noughtscross {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] visBoard = new String[3][3];
        int[][] board = new int[3][3];
        boolean[][] check = new boolean[3][3];
        int total, diag, moves, mod, xcoord, ycoord;
        boolean draw = false, gamewon = false;
        String symbol, play1, play2;

        //Initialising Board
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                visBoard[i][j] = "[ ]";
                board[i][j] = 0;
                check[i][j] = false;
            }
        }for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                System.out.print(visBoard[i][j]);
            }System.out.print("\n");
        }

        //Getting Names
        System.out.println("Player 1 - Enter your name");
        play1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Player 2 - Enter your name");
        play2 = sc.nextLine();
        //
        moves = 0;
        symbol = " X ";
        do{
            do{
                //Get Coords
                System.out.println("X Coordinate");
                xcoord = sc.nextInt() -1;
                System.out.println("Y Coordinate");
                ycoord = sc.nextInt() -1;

                if(check[xcoord][ycoord] == true){
                    System.out.println("Not a valid move!");
                }
            }while(check[xcoord][ycoord] == true);

            //Making move
            check[xcoord][ycoord] = true;
            visBoard[xcoord][ycoord] = symbol;
            if(symbol.equals(" X ")){
                board[xcoord][ycoord] = 1;
            }else if(symbol.equals(" O ")){
                board[xcoord][ycoord] = 5;
            }else{
                System.out.println("You've messed up James");
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    System.out.print(visBoard[i][j]);
                }System.out.print("\n");
            }

            //Check if game has won
            //columns
            total = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    total = total + board[j][i];
                }if(total == 15 || total == 3){
                    gamewon = true;
                }
            }total = 0;
            //rows
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                    total = total + board[i][j];
                }if(total == 15 || total == 3){
                    gamewon = true;
                }
            }total = 0;
            //diagonals
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                total = total + board[i][i];
            }if(total == 15 || total == 3){
                gamewon = true;
            }total = 0;
            diag = 2;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                total = total + board[i][diag];
                diag--;
            }if(total == 15 || total == 3){
                gamewon = true;
            }
            System.out.println(gamewon);
            moves++;
            if(gamewon == false){
                if(moves == 9){
                    System.out.println("Game has been drawn! No one wins!");
                }else{
                    mod = moves % 2;
                    if(mod == 0){
                        symbol = " X ";
                    }else{
                        symbol = " O ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }while(gamewon == false);

        if(gamewon == true){
            if(symbol.equals(" X ")){
                System.out.println("Winner is "+play1);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Winner is "+play2);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Game is drawn");
        }

    }
}
```

Once the game runs through and someone has won, it doesn't stop the loop even though the boolean variable gamewon is true which should stop the while loop.

If this runs fine and works with you it might be something with my eclipse, if not then please tell what is wrong.
JimiiBee

Comment: Step through it in the debugger? Some random notes: 1) X is going to win after playing ANY three moves, given your win conditions. 2) The game will never draw because you need a `break;` statement after `System.out.println("Game has been drawn! No one wins!");`

Comment: Thank you! I used break and it works fully now. I added break in the position you said, ran it through to see if O's would win, and it does.

Comment: Great! I'll submit it as an answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(moves == 9){
    System.out.println("Game has been drawn! No one wins!");
}
```

Should be:

```
if(moves == 9){
    System.out.println("Game has been drawn! No one wins!");
    break;
}
```